# How to copy an existing (custom themed) site to a new domain

Tags: domain, codex, clone-site

I'm trying to find a way of duplicating an existing Wordpress site that uses a custom theme to a new domain.
Once it's there I'll do a redesign of the site and redirect the old url to the new one.

Just briefly... I tried following the instructions @ http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress 
but when it told me to 
"3.Go back to your OLD blog and go to options and change the url (both of them) to that of your new site." It logged me out and caused about 3 hours of trying to get it fixed again !!

So, my question is - how do I copy an existing, custom WP site & theme (including posts etc.) onto a new domain ?

I'm a complete noob at Wordpress and would very much appreciate any help given... Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a new domain, it's pretty simple:

1. Install WordPress on the NEW domain
2. Copy `wp-content/themes` and `wp-content/plugin` from the OLD domain to the NEW domain (using FTP)
3. Activate the Theme on the NEW domain
4. Activate Plugins on the NEW domain
5. Delete generic content (hello world post, about page, etc.) from the NEW domain
6. Export *all content* from the OLD domain, via `Dashboard -> Tools -> Export`
7. Import the just-exported file in the NEW domain, via `Dashboard -> Tools -> Import`. **Important**: be sure to check/enable the option to download/install attachments

That should pretty much be it.

Comment: Hi Chip, thanks for the reply.
I've done as you suggested, but when I Activate the Theme on the new domain, I seem to loose all CSS styles.

Comment: How are those CSS styles implemented? Custom Theme Options? Custom CSS Plugin? Something else?

Comment: Sorry about the delay Chip, I tried to get ahead of myself and needed to re-install the WP site again.

Comment: I'm not sure how the CSS is referenced. SNM is the name of our custom theme...

On the original site I can see the css file here: http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/snm/style.css

The interesting thing is, once I've applied the snm theme - we lose all the styling.  Whenever I try and browse to another part of the site,it logs me out and I then get a 404 error.  Looking at the URL - it is trying to find the page on my old site.
eg: I click on "posts" it takes me to oldsite.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=newsite.com

Comment: Does your Theme have any hard-coded URLs in it, for any reason?

Comment: Hi Chip, thanks once again for waiting for my reply !
My last problem (being redirected) is now solved. It was the old `define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com'); `

I followed the rest of your instructions and essentially - I'm there !

Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to download a plugin such as BackUpWordPress and create a full backup of your old site.

Then FTP into your new host or same host but to the new domain and extract the downloaded files into there.

There's a database also included in your zip.

That might be slightly confusing or possibly for more advanced users. But others may see this post and find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also:

1. Copy files from current production site to local dev site
2. Create user in MySQL (phpMyAdmin)
3. Export `localhost.sql` file from current production site (phpMyAdmin)
4. Import `localhost.sql` file to local dev site (phpMyAdmin)
5. Paste this code into the second line of **your loaded theme**'s `functions.php`

`NOTE:` For more information, see: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-migrate-a-wordpress-site-to-a-new-domain-and-hosting/

`php
<?php
  // If your local copy is served from /www/site/
  update_option ( 'siteurl', 'http://localdev.net/site' );
  update_option ( 'home', 'http://localdev.net/site' );`

6. Load site in your Web Browser
7. Done

FINAL STEP: COmment out those two lines from the functions.php

I find this is much faster and less mentally taxing than the accepted answer. It's like two steps after you zip your existing site. Paste it into your desired folder, export import the DB, then add that line to functions.php, boom done.